# Hahn Banach theorem for locally convex topological vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Given a locally convex topological vector space $X$, and a closed proper subspace $Y \subset X$. Take $x \in X \setminus Y$. Is it true we can find a continuous linear functional $f : X \to \mathbb R$, such that $f(x) \neq 0$, and $f|_Y \equiv 0$. I know that this is true for normed vector spaces. However, can we do this for general topological vector spaces?

Comment: Apply the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) (the second part) with compact set $\{x\}$ and and closed set $Y$.

Comment: @Aweygan Would like to write that as an answer?

Comment: @barto I don't really see the point, but alright

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem), with the compact set $\{x\}$ and the closed set $Y$.  We obtain some $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)\notin f(Y)$ (actually we obtain something stronger, but not necessary here).  As $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, $f(Y)$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb F$ ($=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).  Hence $f(Y)=\{0\}$, and $f(x)\neq0$.